# Get crashlytics log for submodule project in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, crashlytics

I've an Xcode project (say with bundle id: com.project1.abc) which also includes another Xcode project (say with bundle id: com.project2.abc). Now I have integrated crashlytics for my main project and have created the same one in crashlytics with bundle id com.project1.abc and it works fine and I get all the logs in my main project. Now I need to log some data in the sub project the one with bundle id: com.project2.abc. How do I go about it? Will I need to create a new project section in crashlytics with new bundle id:com.project2.abc? Or is there any other way that logs in submodule can be also mapped to the main project in crashlytics?

Right now I just add the crashlytic code on the main project Appdelegate file as the Appdelegate file in the subproject doesn't get called.

```
[Fabric with:@[[Crashlytics class]]];
```

I'm using Xcode 8.3 Beta, Swift 3.2.

Comment: to integrate Fabric's Crashlytics kit you need to include APIKey in Info.plist. Have you tried setting same key for both your projects?

Comment: Yes, and although I've included the crashlytics framework in sub project as well it doesn't seem to recognize when I try to import it.

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the same onboarding steps for com.project2.abc (in your example) it will appear in your Fabric dashboard as a new app and you should be all set: https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/manual-install